# ESP32 Stepper Motor Control PCB Design Validation

Tags: pcb, control, stepper-motor, esp32, layout

I am presently in the process of developing a PCB designed to act as a foundational board for the precise control of a stepper motor. The system incorporates an LCD display and various sensors for control purposes. Before proceeding with the PCB fabrication, I would greatly value your expertise in validating my design.

Main components used in the design:

Starting with the Hi-Link 20M12, providing 12V and 1.6A, the voltage is then regulated down to 7V using an LM2596 step-down converter. Following this, the 7V power is further reduced to 5V through LM7805 linear regulators. One branch supplies 3.3V AMS1117 linear regulator to power the ESP32, while the other branch is reserved for other peripherals. Additionally, the circuit features an RTC DS3231 for clock display and a TMC2209 driver for motor control.

Layout:

I've positioned the step-down converter and linear regulators in close proximity to the power supply to minimize inductance. Additionally, I widened the voltage paths to decrease resistance. On the board, I made a separation between the voltage section and the ESP section. Given the presence of 230V AC voltage for the power supply, I ensured wide paths between the connectors. To prevent short circuits, I omitted the upper and lower GND layers in this area and added cutouts to separate the connectors.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I had problems with C7 below 1 uF and Arduino IDE on some PCs.